# create an array from object using underscore

Tags: underscore.js

I have following json as sample

```
var employee=[{sex:'M',id:1},{sex:'M',id:3},{sex:'f',id:4},{sex:'f',id:5}]
```

I want following array

```
maleIds=[1,3]
femaleIds=[4,5]

 var testFilter=_.filter(employee,function(obj) {
                return obj.sex=='M';
            });

            var testMap=_.map(testFilter, function(value, key){
                return { name : key, value : value };
            });
```

How can I create array from object using specific criteria ?

_filter / _map they return whole object . I want only sex value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [**partition**](http://underscorejs.org/#partition) the employee data. This will return an array of 2 arrays; the first array contains all the males and the second the females. Then use [**pluck**](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) on the partitioned data to get the ids:

```
var employee=[{sex:'M',id:1},{sex:'M',id:3},{sex:'f',id:4},{sex:'f',id:5}]

var partitions = _.partition(employee, {sex: 'M'})

var maleIds = _.pluck(partitions[0], 'id');
var femaleIds = _.pluck(partitions[1], 'id');
```

```js
 var employee=[{sex:'M',id:1},{sex:'M',id:3},{sex:'f',id:4},{sex:'f',id:5}]

 var partitions = _.partition(employee, {sex: 'M'})

 var maleIds = _.pluck(partitions[0], 'id');
 var femaleIds = _.pluck(partitions[1], 'id');

document.getElementById('males').textContent = JSON.stringify(maleIds);
document.getElementById('females').textContent = JSON.stringify(femaleIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<p>
  males <pre id="males"></pre>
  females <pre id="females"></pre>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks very much . i am very new to underscore , and project time limit didn't let me to study whole documentation .